# C++: map<wstring,wstring> Getting second from first

Tags: c++, dictionary, wstring

I have a

```
map <wstring,wstring>.
```

I have inserted pairs like this:

```
m_Translations.Content().insert(pair<wstring,wstring>(L"rome",L"roma"));
m_Translations.Content().insert(pair<wstring,wstring>(L"water",L"aqua"));
```

How could I determine the translation for "water" from the map? 
In other words: I would like to get the second item from the first.
The search is case-sensitive.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: `wstring s = m_Translations.Content()[L"water"];`

Comment: @AlexFarber: You probably don't want to insert an empty entry if it's missing.

Comment: @Mike Seymour - this is the difference between a hint posted as comment, and full answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit weird question. What about the default way of accessing a map with `operator[]`?

```
wstring aqua = m_Translations.Content()[L"water"];
```

In case you are not sure whether a translation exists or not, you can check it with the `find` method:

```
const auto& dict = m_Translations.Content();
auto pAqua = dict.find(L"water");

if (pAqua != dict.end())
{
  // Found it!
}
else
{
  // Not there...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. What is this "auto"?

Comment: This is a C++11 style. It means that the variable type is automatically deduced from the initializing expression. You can rewrite it with explicit type declaration.

Comment: Why not use method `at`? An exception will thrown, if no element exists with specified key.

Comment: @Mikhail I have a question, please, just for curiosity. Would it be possible to make the search case-insensitive as well?

Comment: @soon It is also a proper way. I think it is a matter of choice. However, there might be some performance issues with exception handling if this request is processed multiple times.

Comment: @tmighty Yes, there are multiple ways to do it. The simplest is to provide a third template parameter to `std::map` which compares keys.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [operator[]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) available on `std::map`.

For example:

```
map<wstring, wstring> myMap = m_Translations.Content();

myMap.insert(pair<wstring, wstring>(L"rome", L"roma"));
myMap.insert(pair<wstring, wstring>(L"water", L"aqua"));

// waterText value would be 'aqua'
wstring waterText = myMap[L"water"];
```